# Scanning / printing server software with gui and file sharing

Tags: printing, scanning, raspberry-pi, cloud

I am trying to build a home scanning / printing service with a raspberry pi, so no one has to download drivers and all these operations can be centralized. Currently, it can be controlled remotely by logging into the raspberry pi.

However, since the scanner is usually not in the same room as the computer you are using, it would be nice if you could have a big button to press right next to the scanner, so you don't have to go back and forth scanning one page at a time. Of course, simple scan does the job.

My problem is that there are users that are not tech-savvy enough to retrieve the result of their scans via ssh, once done. I have though of providing a web interface to download the result of the scans, but this is such a common problem that I am quite sure that there is a software that does this. But my google-fu wasn't enough to find it out.

So, what I would like is a software that:

- acts as a very basic local "cloud" service, in the sense that you can upload files to and download from (no login or accounts required)
- has a web interface that allows to

  - upload files to be printed
  - download scanned files
- has a gui interface that allows to

  - print uploaded files
  - scan multiple times, and allows for elementary image manipulation with these files, like combining them into a single pdf
- is free
- can be installed on Raspbian, and is Linux-compatible client-side

Optional features:

- the gui interface is comfortable with a small touchpad screen, as it's what my raspberry pi has.
- the software is open source, and easily customizable
- the software is cross-platform client side
- the software has a nice interface

Thanks!

Comment: maybe a simple NAS and some bash automation with a button connected via the GPIO pins could work for you. simply let uploaded files(in a specific folder) trigger a script to print and delete or move the file and let push of the button trigger a script to scan and save to a specific folder